# Passing string array as arguements is not giving expected result

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception

I m working on a program, where I retrieve string from db and store into a String array. Now I pass this array to method in another class. Say The string array length is 10. Now I will check for particular occurence of a char and I will do some work. Now my problem is I am able to store the value from db into string array. But what problem I am getting is giving null pointer exception. As the loop which reads the string array in another method reads the last index array.

The program:

This is where I store the Db values into array. These arrays are global declarations.

```
 while(rst.next())
        {
        allitems[i]=rst.getString("transitems");
        alltuv[i]=rst.getString("tuv");


        }
```

Now pass this array into a method of same class.

```
 Window2 n=new Window2();

    n.calculateTWU(allitems,alltuv);
```

Now I pass this array into another method of different class.

```
  CalculateTWU ctw=new CalculateTWU();
  String avalue=ctw.calctA(s1, s2,"A"); //s1 and s2 are the string arrays s1=allitems     and s2=alltuv.
```

The method in another class say Class B

```
 public String calctA(String[] a1,String[] a2,String indexstr)

{

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{


 int is= a1[i].indexOf(indexstr);



if(is==-1)
{


}
else
{
valadd=Integer.parseInt(a2[i])+valadd;

}

}
 return String.valueOf(valadd);
```

}

Stack Trace :

```
      MNOETTAOHX   // these are strings


  BOCOPVBLEV


  MIAISEUECV


  MGUXPXPEDX


  EQMWLRVKZG


  MNFBFAXQNT


  YZKDHMVSSA




java.lang.NullPointerException
    at datasets.CalculateTWU.calctA(CalculateTWU.java:27)
    at datasets.Window2.calculateTWU(Window2.java:205)
    at datasets.Window2.jButton1ActionPerformed(Window2.java:146)
    at datasets.Window2.access$000(Window2.java:20)
    at datasets.Window2$1.actionPerformed(Window2.java:68)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
```

Comment: the complete code please, not parts of it.

Comment: Preferably indented, too, it really does make it easier to reason about.

Comment: the code is some what large. So thats why posted part of it

Comment: Easy to indent if using Netbeans: alt-shift-f

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array, by default all it's items are `null` until you populate them. In your example, you have 9 strings, but are looping on 10 items in the array. The last one is `null`, and hence your `NullPointerException`.
You can avoid this by explicitly checking:

```
public String calctA(String[] a1, String[] a2, String indexstr) {
    for(int i=0; i < a1.length; ++i)  {
        if (a1[i] != null) {
            int is= a1[i].indexOf(indexstr);
            // rest of your code...
```

Comment: But actually I am passing 10 elements which are inside the array. But When I run forloop in CalctA method the last index is read and after that null pointer exception is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

```
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) \\ What line is this in the class?
```

change to

```
  for(int i =0; i < a1.length;i++)
```

The problem with your stack trace is since the whole class isn't present it's hard to determine where exactly the NullPointerException is occurring.

Comment: actually the length of the array is 10 and it is constant.